# Convert a String[] into an object and back into a String[]?

Tags: c#, object, casting, split, boxing

I'm putting a concatenated string into the Tag property of a component this way:

```
Tag = String.Format("{0};{1};{2}", AThis, AThat, ATheOtherThing);
```

Now how do I get it out, as Tag is an object? Trying to do this:

```
String[] someStuff = Tag.Split(';');
```

I get, "*'object' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `Tag` is `object` but the `Split` method is on `String`.  You need to cast `Tag` back to `String` in order to call `Split`

```
string[] someStuff = ((string)Tag).Split(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

As object can be cast to and from any other data type, you can skip the string.Format() completely, and assign a string[]

```
Tag = new string[] { AThis, AThat, ATheOtherThing };
```

and

```
string[] someStuff = (string[])Tag;
```

or use object[] if AThis, AThat, ATheOtherThing are different data types.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some driving need for it as a string another way would be a struct that held your three values, then just set tag to it, and to get it back cast it. No more formating and splitting then. More importantly if you add a fourth item, refactor the struct, job done.

Answer (score 0):

A safe way to convert the `Tag` back to `string` is to use the `as` keyword. If the `Tag` contains something else than a `string` it does not throw an exception but returns `null`

```
string s = Tag as string;
string[] someStuff = null;
if (s != null) {
    someStuff = s.Split(';');
}
```